# How come root can do this, but sudo can't?

Tags: bash, debian, permissions, sudo, non-root-user

I am set up as a `sudoer` on my Debian machine, and I use it all the time to install software etc... I came across this interesting situation that I am scratching my head about:

I tried to enable the fancy progress bar in apt using this command:

```
sudo echo 'Dpkg::Progress-Fancy "1";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99progressbar
```

I have permissions issues:

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99progressbar: Permission denied
```

However, if I `su`, then run the command, everything just works.

Why is this so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because

```
 sudo cmd > file
```

is interpreted as

```
(sudo cmd) > file
```

by your shell. I.e. the redirect is done as your own user.

The way I get around that is using

```
cmd | sudo tee file
```

Addition: That will also show the output of `cmd` on your console, if you don't want that you'll have to redirect it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, `>` is the command by shell itself (redirection is done by the non-root shell itself) 
When you use `su`, it runs as a root shell which allows you to redirect for root-owned files

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` has problems, because it runs the command portion. After the redirect, `sudo` is not effective anymore.

You can do this instead :

```
sudo bash -c "Your commands here > output_file"
```

carefully escaping the single or double quotes in the commands between quotes, in the nesting order you use them.

**EDIT:**

Explanation in a little deeper detail

When you run a script, you are actually creating a new sub-shell and your script runs in this sub-shell, but the output comes back to the current shell. Your new sub-shell where you run this script is run with `sudo` privileges, so the scripts runs effectively as root. But when the run finishes, the shell exits and your `sudo` goes * pooof *. The output comes back to your current, non-privileged shell. If you are expecting it to be written at a privileged location, it is not going to happen. Hence, running the new shell and the whole enchilada, inside a well defined `bash` shell, makes it possible. Because, at this point, your command and output are all handled by the `sudo` enabled shell, not half way as in the original case.

Comment: Partly correct, and partly backwards. Actually the shell tries to open `output_file` for writing *before* it even thinks about running sudo. But what really matters isn't the sequence of events, it's which process is responsible for what.